# How to use MobileWifi framework in xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I import `mobilewifi framework` to my `objective c` class. While importing `mobilewifi framework` it contains `command tool`, there is no header files. Please advise.

Comment: I think this is a private library and you cant upload build with private library

Comment: https://github.com/davidmurray/wifi/issues/16  this may help you

Comment: While am using this (https://github.com/davidmurray/wifi/issues/16) am getting below error. This is not even compiling.  Error : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_WiFiManagerClientCopyNetworks", referenced from:
-[HomeScreenViewController scanWifiClick] in HomeScreenViewController.o
"_WiFiManagerClientCreate", referenced from:
-[HomeScreenViewController scanWifiClick] in HomeScreenViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)